# How to Convert CImg<t> to TBitmap?

Tags: c++, c++builder, cimg, c++builder-xe2

in my project i am using CImg library, after image processing i want to show my image result in a TBitmap in C++ Builder XE2, please someone tell me how to do that. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a processed image to a file using `CImg<>.save_bmp()` then open it with `TFileStream` and then load it with `TBitmap.LoadFromStream()`.

As an alternative you can create a memory mapped file or a name pipe then transform `HANDLE` to `FILE*`

```
HANDLE hFile  = CreateFile(...);
int    handle = _open_osfhandle((LONG)hFile, _mode);
FILE*  f      = fdopen(handle, szMode);
```

and pass it to `CImg<>.save_bmp(FILE*)` and then load bitmap using `THandleStream` and `TBitmap.LoadFromStream()`.